# textures with transparent on OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I want to make fonts on my opengl window by using texture.

I use this way:

1.

```
gldisable(gl_blend);
gldisable(gl_texture_2d);
```

2.

draw a quad of background color

3.

```
glenable(gl_blend);
glblendfunc(gl_src_alpha,gl_one_minus_src_alpha);
glenable(gl_texture_2d);
glbindtexture(gl_texture_2d,txtr);
```

4.

draw texture

5.

```
gldisable(gl_texture_2d);
glblendfunc(gl_dst_alpha,gl_dst_alpha);
```

6.

draw front color

But now I found when I draw front color while using color_mix,it will also mix the background color at the place where the texture are transparent.

What can I do to make the font can use the front color and the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you're using legacy OpenGL:

You can set the texture to be drawn directly in foreground color, like this:

```
// Preparation
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor3d(bgR,bgG,bgB); // Set background color

    /* Draw background quad here */

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, yourFontTexture);
    glColor3d(fgR,fgG,fgB); // Set foreground color

    /* Draw texture quads here*/
}
```

This requires that your font texture is white on transparent background. The texture colors are multiplied with the active color when drawn.

Note that with this method you can draw colored text over anything you like, and you do not explicitly need to draw a background rectangle if the background is already of the desired color.

Comment: I've tried but the frontcolor was not painted,The frontcolor was still the color in the texture.How to mix the frontcolor and the texture?

Answer (score 0):

What is the intention of first drawing a quad with the background color? I think what you really want there is to either use the `GL_DECAL` texture environment mode, if you insist on using the outdated fixed function pipeline. Or if using modern OpenGL *(recommended)* write an appropriate shader that takes the background color into account.

Suggested fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D u_font_tex;
uniform vec4 u_bkgd_color;
in vec2 v_tex_coord;
out vec4 output_color;

main()
{
     vec4 t = texture(u_font_tex, v_tex_coord);
     output_color = mix(u_bkgd_color, t, t.a);
}
```